# How to download portion of video with youtube-dl command? (2)

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

This question has already been posted. However, I want to know if it is possible to only download a portion of a youtube video using a combination of youtube-dl and ffmpeg without downloading the entire file and then cutting it.

Please and thank you.